# Три ListView зависящих друг от друга по формуле

Tags: android, массивы, listview

В приложении создал три поля ListView, в каждом выводится значения из соответствующих Array (которых тоже три). Нужно сделать так, чтобы эти значения выводились в зависимости от двух других. Пользователь выкрутил два значения в первых двух полях ListView, срабатывает формула, получаем, допустим, "0.48", проверяем к какому ближайшему значению из третьего Array оно ближе и выводим его в третьем ListView.

Я новичок, первый мой вопрос на stackoverflow, не судите строго, готов к конструктивной критике.

Код **activity_main.xml**, где создано три *ListView*:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/center"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/center" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/center" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Код **MainActivity.java** Создал в *onCreate*:

```
ListView listView_3 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_3);
ListView listView_2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_2);
ListView listView_1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, iso);
listView_3.setAdapter(adapter3);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aperture);
listView_2.setAdapter(adapter2);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,             
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, time_1);
listView_1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Ну и сами Array в **MainActivity.java** :

```
String [] iso = { "0.8", "1", "1.2", "1.6", "2", "2.5", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "10", "12", "16", "20", "25", "32", "40", "50", "64", "80", "100", "125", "160", "200", "250", "320", "400", "500", "640", "800", "1000", "1250", "1600", "2000", "2500", "3200", "4000", "5000", "6400", "12800", "25600", "51200", "102400"};

String [] aperture = { "f / 1.0", "f / 1.1", "f / 1.2", "f / 1.4", "f / 1.6", "f / 1.8", "f / 2.0", "f /2.2", "f / 2.5", "f / 2.8", "f / 3.2", "f / 3.5", "f / 4.0", "f / 4.5", "f / 5.0", "f / 5.6", "f / 6.3", "f / 7.1", "f / 8", "f / 9", "f / 10", "f / 11", "f / 13", "f / 14", "f / 16", "f / 18", "f / 20", "f / 22", "f / 25", "f / 28", "f / 32", "f / 36", "f / 40", "f / 45", "f / 51", "f / 57", "f / 64", "f / 72", "f / 80", "f / 90", "f / 102", "f / 114", "f / 128", "f / 144", "f / 161", "f / 181", "f / 203", "f / 228", "f / 256", "f / 287", "f / 323", "f / 362", "f / 407", "f / 456", "f / 512" };

String [] time_1 = { "32s", "26s", "20s", "16s", "13s", "10s", "8s", "6s", "5s", "4s", "3s", "2.5s", "2s", "1.6s", "1.3s", "1s", "1/1.3", "1/1.6", "1/2", "1/2.5", "1/3", "1/4", "1/5", "1/6", "1/8", "1/10", "1/13", "1/15", "1/20", "1/25", "1/30", "1/40", "1/50", "1/60", "1/80", "1/100", "1/125", "1/160", "1/200", "1/250", "1/320", "1/400", "1/500", "1/640", "1/800", "1/1000", "1/1250", "1/1600", "1/2000", "1/2500", "1/3200", "1/4000", "1/5000", "1/6400", "1/8000"};
```

Допустим, в time_1 произведя вычисления получили 31 s, но в массиве String [] time_1 его нет, нужно вычислить ближайшее значение, которое существует в String [] time_1 и вывести его в ListView.

UPD.
То есть, мне нужно три массива String для вывода на экран и три массива float для проведения вычислений? Еще такой вопрос, все значения в мои массивы String не входят, могут появляться новые значения, как быть с этим?

UPD.
Округлять нормально, используя Math.round();
Пользователь не может добавлять значения, они сами генерируются (по формуле)
Это должно выглядеть как на iPhone(например выбор даты, Вы прокручиваете список с месяцами и останавливаете на нужном вам месяце). Например, пользователь задал ISO = 400 и aperture = f / 5.0. Срабатывает формула, для случая, когда пользователем выбрано ISO и Aperture, считаем Time, получаем 1.2 s, после нормального округления, наш ListView должен прокрутить до значения 1.3 и остановиться.

Comment: дополняйте вопрос в самом вопросе (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему.

Comment: Для начала, я так понимаю, что никакой логики вычеслений вы не писали? если вам нужны какие то вычисления, то их нужно проводить с числами, а не строками, ваши массивы содержат текст, который не пригоден для подобных вычислений. этот момент нужно решить в первую очередь, например, создать массивы типа `float`, а строковые символы дописывать только при выводе на экран или как вы думали проводить вычисления? потом по какому принципу округлять, к ближайшему по значению или следующему по массиву? то есть, напр. для 30 сек будет 32 или 26?

Comment: не нужно вам три массива String, просто при выводе на экран к числам дописываете свои "f/" и "s". что все же насчет ближайшего значения, оно должно быть следующим по списку или ближним по значению? новые значения может добавлять пользователь или при очередном апдтейте приложения они могут добавиться?

Comment: зачем вам вообще для вычесленного (третьего)  значения ListView? вы же его не выбираете, а расчитываете .. как это вообще должно выглядеть? список позиционируется на нужную строку или что. думаю вам больше подойдет что то вроде NumberPicker, чем списки для первых двух и простой вывод результата (третьего значения) в TextView ..

Comment: ListView совершенно не предназначены для таких функций, как вы описали и использовать их таким образрм не получится. Колесики, которые крутятся это NumberPicker для ваших задач его нужно будет сильно кастомизировать

Comment: например вот [вариант виджета на github](https://github.com/lantouzi/WheelView-Android/blob/master/README.md). другие [возможные варианты](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+wheel&type=)